# Why does the javascript style property not work as expected?

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
   <head>
       <style type="text/css">
       #wow{
          border : 10px solid red;
          width: 20px;
          height: 20px;

       }
       </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="wow"></div>
      <script>
        var val = document.getElementById("wow");
        alert(val.style.length);
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

This is my code, why is `val.style.length` 0?  Because I defined 3 properties, I expect it to be 3

Comment: you mean it should be 3 because you have setted 3 property inside #wow{}?

Comment: There's no `style` attribute on the element, so there's nothing in the style object within the element's DOM object.

Comment: `style.length` only works for inline styles.

Comment: he's half right - the `.style` property only reflects the state of the `style` attribute, and nothing inherited from style sheets.

Comment: Can you describe why you need to do this?

Comment: You want to count the css rules defined for a class/id?

Comment: i just wanted to count the css rules defined for the div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An element's `style` property only reflects inline styles. It is essentially a way of getting (and indeed setting) inline styles.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.style):

> [the `style` property] is not useful for learning about the element's style in general, since it represents only the CSS declarations set in the element's inline style attribute, not those that come from style rules elsewhere, such as style rules in the  section, or external style sheets.

You can get all the styles applied to an element with `window.getComputedStyle(element)`:

```
alert(window.getComputedStyle(val).length);
```

However, this probably won't do what you want, since it provides *all* the style properties on an element, even if they are still the default. In my browser (Chrome, FWIW), that means it always returns `285`. This shouldn't be a surprise. The browser has a "built in" stylesheet that provides the defaults for all elements, after all.